# Edit ExceptionSample so it can catch exceptions wherein text is entered as String input instead of integer data type input

Tags: java, exception, mathematical-expressions

How to catch an exception if the the input is string instead of integer?
It's confusing me since they used `Try`, `Catch`, `Finally` which looks new to me. Please enlighten me thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ExceptionSample {
    public static void main (String[]args){
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
       int dividend, divisor, quotient;
       System.out.print("Enter dividend: ");
       dividend = s.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter divisor: ");
       divisor = s.nextInt();
       try {
        quotient = dividend/divisor;
        System.out.println(dividend + " / " + divisor + " = " + quotient);
       }
       catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
        System.out.println("Divisor cannot be 0.");
        System.out.println("Try again.");
       }
        finally  {
    System.out.println("Thank you.");
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would go something like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

int dividend, divisor, quotient;
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter dividend: ");
    try {
        dividend = s.nextInt();
    } 
    catch (java.util.InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Dividend Entry! Try again...\n"); 
        s.nextLine(); // consume the Enter Key Hit.
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
    
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter divisor: ");
    try {
        divisor = s.nextInt();
        if (divisor == 0) {
            throw new java.util.InputMismatchException();
        }
    }
    catch (java.util.InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Divisor Entry! Try again...\n"); 
        s.nextLine(); // consume the Enter Key Hit.
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
    
try {
    quotient = dividend / divisor;
    System.out.println(dividend + " / " + divisor + " = " + quotient);
}
catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
    System.out.println("Divisor cannot be 0.");
    System.out.println("Try again.");
}
finally {
    System.out.println("Thank you.");
    s.close();
}
```

When the **Scanner#nextInt()** method is used and one or more alpha characters are supplied a **InputMismatchException** is thrown. We trap this exception and use it to our advantage for validating the numerical input.

Comment: Been figuring this out since yesterday, thank you!